# how to convert WIN32_FIND_DATA to string?

Tags: c++, windows

im using WIN32_FIND_DATA to store the data findfirstfile outputs. i want the file location (C:\file) as a string but i don't know how to get it or any other data from it.

Edit: here is my code

```
PTSTR pszFileName; 
PTSTR pszFileName2[100];
if (search_handle) 
{ 
    do 
    {
        pszFileName = file.cFileName;
        pszFileName2[loop] = pszFileName;
        Sleep(100);
        loop++;

        std::wcout << file.cFileName << std::endl;
    }
    while(FindNextFile(search_handle,&file)); 

    CloseHandle(search_handle); 
}
```

Comment: What reference material are you using? If it mentions that data type but doesn't describe its contents, then we should make a note to never recommend that resource to others. You should consider using MSDN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365740(VS.85).aspx) is a struct.  Check out the `cFileName` member.

For example:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData = {0};
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(pszPattern, &FindData);

if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
   do
   {
      PTSTR pszFileName = FindData.cFileName;

      // TODO: Use pszFileName in some way...

   } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData));

   FindClose(hFind);
}
```

**Update in response to comments**

In this example the storage for the string is on the stack, and the same buffer is used for every call.  This means that every `FindNextFile()` overwrites the previous string.  You will have to make a copy of the string.

Since you're using C++ and classes in `std` I suggest you store it in `std::string` (or better yet, make sure you define `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` and use `wstring`.)  Initializing a new `string` class will do the allocation and copying on your behalf.

Alternatively you can copy the string using the typical C techniques (for example: using `malloc` + `memcpy`, `strdup`, or similar), but it sounds like you might want a refresher in strings, pointers, and memory allocation in C before you get to that.

By the way -- to check for error, your code compares the find handle against `NULL`; this is incorrect. `FindFirstFile()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (which works out to `(HANDLE)-1`) on failure.  Additionally, to close the handle you will want to use `FindClose()`, and not `CloseHandle()`.  (A "find handle" isn't really a handle to a kernel object in the same sense that a file handle, handle to a module, or a thread or process handle is.  They've just overloaded the type.)

Comment: it works ok but only once i can't put it in a array (look at my code). i just get the same file, it will use one array for each file but they all have the name of the last file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're storing the address of the filename in your array. Each time that `FindNextFile()` is called, it replaces the data in the struct with the information for the next file. You need to allocate memory for the string in your array, and then copy the string from the structure to your array (using something like `strncpy_s()`, probably).

Your code is just storing the pointer to the filename member of the struct, once per found file. If you look at the address each element in the array is pointing to, they're all pointing to the same place.

Comment: o :( ok how do i copy it, the data?

Comment: @blood That's a pretty big topic, that would be hard to cover in an answer here. I'll echo @asveikau - you should refresh yourself with how pointers and strings work in C/C++.